# pyblue failed to execute mgmt cmd 'scanend' on raspberry pi3

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

The code is following, which copied from either pyblue or somewhere else, 
the hciconfig or bluetoothctl can see the device, and do lescan, but the following python code can not do the scan and getting the error below:

```
from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate

class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
   def __init__(self):
      DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

   def handleDiscovery(self, dev, isNewDev, isNewData):
      if isNewDev:
          print ("Discovered device", dev.addr)
      elif isNewData:
          print ("Received new data from", dev.addr)

scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
devices = scanner.scan(10.0)

for dev in devices:
  print ("Device %s (%s), RSSI=%d dB" % (dev.addr, dev.addrType, dev.rssi))
    for (adtype, desc, value) in dev.getScanData():
       print ("  %s = %s" % (desc, value))
```

I am getting the following error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 679, in scan
    self.start(passive=passive)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 624, in start
    self._mgmtCmd(self._cmd()+"end")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 276, in _mgmtCmd
     "Failed to execute mgmt cmd '%s'" % (cmd))
```

Comment: Please post the *complete* Traceback!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] and [mcve] for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: failed at the scan : File "bt2.py", line 14, in <module>
        devices = scanner.scan(10.0)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 679, in scan
        self.start(passive=passive)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 624, in start
        self._mgmtCmd(self._cmd()+"end")
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 276, in _mgmtCmd
        "Failed to execute mgmt cmd '%s'" % (cmd))
bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Failed to execute mgmt cmd 'scanend'